# Using Bootstrap tablesorter with ASP.NET gridview

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, pagination, tablesorter

I´m using the following tablesorter widget in my gridviews:
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html

I'm facing a problem with the pagination of the Gridview. I have not been able to Paginate the results, and the search textboxes won't work if I refill the gridview everytime I change the page.

I have the thead enabled in the gridview. And, the gridview is loading it's data in the Page_Load Event.

What's the best approach to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is probably that you are not adding the classes to your HTML code like is in the example of the link you added to the question.

Please, be sure to add the classes correctly.

Comment: I added the Pure html to a FooterTemplate exactly as the example, thank you.